# Duvida SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Galera estou com bastante dificuldade nessa pergunta alguém pode me ajudar?

Tabelas :

```
 CREATE TABLE Funcionario
(
 Cod_Func int Identity not null,
 Nome_Func varchar(100) not null,
 Data_CadFunc smalldatetime not null Default
Getdate(),
 Sexo_Func char(01) not null Default
'F',
 Sal_Func decimal(10,2) not null Default 200,
 End_Func varchar(100) not null,
 Constraint PK_Func Primary Key(Cod_Func),
 Constraint CH_Func1 Check(Data_CadFunc>=Getdate()),

 Constraint CH_Func2 Check(Sexo_Func IN
('F','M')),
 Constraint CH_Func3 Check(Sal_Func >=0)
)

CREATE TABLE Dependente
(
 Cod_Dep int identity not null,
 Cod_Func int not null,
 Nome_Dep varchar(100) not null,
 Data_NascDep smalldatetime not null,
 Sexo_Dep char(01) not null Default
'F',
 Constraint PK_Dep Primary Key(Cod_Dep),
 Constraint FK_Dep Foreign
Key(Cod_Func)References Funcionario(Cod_Func),
 Constraint CH_Dep Check(Sexo_Dep IN ('F','M'))
)
```

http://prntscr.com/d268fa
http://prntscr.com/d2684x

Comment: Esse vídeo "tutorial" mostra como fazer isso e inclusive com o mesmo exemplo, falando de funcionário e dependentes/gerente e funcionário https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jl24CvKkOyw

Comment: Qual é a parte em que tens problemas? Algum erro com o código que tens? Podes explicar o que queres fazer? (assim a pergunta fica mais clara)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar um left join para isso:

```
select fun.nome_func, dep.nome_dep
  from funcionario fun
  left join dependente dep
    on dep.cod_func = fun.cod_func;
```

O retorno seria algo do tipo:

```
nome_func | nome_dep
João      | NULL
Maria     | José
Maria     | Alberto
```

A função do join é de mostrar dados de duas tabelas diferentes de forma combinada. Essa combinação deve ter uma condição. Nesse caso a condição é que o cod_func da tabela dependente seja o mesmo que o cod_func da tabela funcionario.

No caso do left join o que ele faz é exibir todos os registro da tabela à esquerda (funcionario) mesmo que a condiçao do join não seja satisteita. Por isso nome_dep aparece como NULL caso joão não possua dependentes.

Answer (score 2):

“*Escreva um comando que mostre o nome de cada funcionário e o nome de cada dependente de que cada funcionário que tem dependentes*”

O enunciado acima me pareceu um pouco ambíguo. O que compreendi é que, dentre os funcionários que têm dependentes, listar o nome do funcionário e o nome do(s) dependente(s).

```
-- código #1
SELECT F.Nome_Func as Funcionário, 
       D.Nome_Dep as Dependente
  from Funcionario as F
       inner join Dependente as D on D.Cod_Func = F.Cod_Func;
```

Mas se o objetivo é listar o nome de todos os funcionários, bem como o nome do(s) respectivo(s) dependente(s), eis outra sugestão:

```
-- código #2
SELECT F.Nome_Func as Funcionário, 
       IsNull(D.Nome_Dep, '--') as Dependente
  from Funcionario as F
       left join Dependente as D on D.Cod_Func = F.Cod_Func;
```